# Invalid POLYGON bigQuery while using ST_GEOGFROMTEXT

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with POLYGON strings and I need to convert them with ST_GEOGFROMTEXT. But I got this error mensage:

"ST_GeogFromText failed: Invalid polygon loop: Edge 1 has duplicate vertex with edge 4; in polygon at position 392"

Is there  way to identify which row returns the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `SAFE.ST_GeogFromText` which will return NULL for erroneous rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `make_valid` parameter of `ST_GEOGFROMTEXT` function - if set to TRUE, the function attempts to correct polygon issues when importing geography data.